# look up activity in azure data factory V2 not Succeeding

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

look up activity in azure data factory V2 not Succeeding
I waited for one hour still it was in Inprogess state and i had to canceled the pipeline run

[activity run screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV7k3.png)

Here is my json file content

```
  [{
    "Name":"xyz",
    "Phone":"xxx"
  },
  {
    "Name":"xyz1",
    "Phone":"xxx1"
  }]
```

**Note : It is working in data preview**

Comment: What is your source? How did you configure you lookup activity? Try adding details, we can't help you with the little to no information you provided.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Today it is working i think there was some bug in adf.

Comment: Awesome then!!!